# how to dump heap contents of a running ruby program?

Tags: ruby, memory-management

how to dump heap contents of a running ruby program ?

how to get the size allocated by this program in the memory

```
array = [1,"hello" , 5.2 , 234567]
puts "hello world"
```

Answer (score 2):

For stats you can use `GC.stat`:

```
GC.stat
=> {:count=>25,
 :heap_used=>464,
 :heap_length=>802,
 :heap_increment=>338,
 :heap_live_num=>120503,
 :heap_free_num=>78575,
 :heap_final_num=>0,
 :total_allocated_object=>721771,
 :total_freed_object=>601268}
```

You can show heap dump with a gem of the same name: https://github.com/Vasfed/heap_dump

Also this recent post will shed some light on matter: http://samsaffron.com/archive/2013/11/22/demystifying-the-ruby-gc